# Why custom move function does not work as std::move

Tags: c++, c++17, move, stdmove

Just to see how std::move works, I tried to mimic (well copied original code)the std::move function; but to my surprise it does not work as std::move. My move function ends-up calling copy ctor instead of move ctor.

```
#include <iostream>

#define My_version

template <class _Ty>
struct remove_reference {
    using type = _Ty;
    using _Const_thru_ref_type = const _Ty;
};
template <class _Ty>
using remove_reference_t = typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type;

#ifdef My_version
template<typename T> // in namespace std
typename remove_reference<T>::type&&
mymove(T&& param)
{
    std::cout << "My_version\n";
    using ReturnType = typename remove_reference<T>::type&&; 
    return static_cast<ReturnType>(param);
}
#else
template <class _Ty>
constexpr remove_reference_t<_Ty>&& mymove(_Ty&& _Arg) noexcept { // forward _Arg as movable
    return static_cast<remove_reference_t<_Ty>&&>(_Arg);
}
#endif // My_version

class simple
{
public:
    simple(int kk) :k(kk) {}
    
    simple(simple&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "move is called \n";
        k = rhs.k;
        rhs.k = -1; //moved
    }

    simple(const simple& rhs)noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "copy is called \n";
        k = rhs.k*10;
    }
    int k;
};

int main()
{
   
        {
            std::cout << "===============================\nmymove\n===============================\n";
            simple a(42);
            simple b = mymove(a);
            std::cout << " after move\nmovedObj.k " << b.k << " originalObj.k " << a.k << "\n";
        }
        {
            std::cout << "\n\n===============================\nstd::move\n===============================\n";
            simple a(42);
            simple b = std::move(a);
            std::cout << "after move\nmovedObj.k " << b.k << " originalObj.k " << a.k << "\n";
        }
   return 0;
}
```

I tried both exact copy of std::move function and slightly different style function as can be seen here separated by #ifdef. Unlike std::move both call copy ctor.

std::move causes move constructor why my move function causes copy.

```
===============================
mymove
===============================
copy is called
 after move
movedObj.k 420 originalObj.k 42


===============================
std::move
===============================
move is called
after move
movedObj.k 42 originalObj.k -1
```

Comment: Your `remove_reference` lacks reference specializations to actually remove something.

Comment: As suggested by @HolyBlackCat Adding two more reference specialisations for remove_reference fixed the problem.                                                                                                            template <class _Ty>
struct remove_reference<_Ty&> {
    using type = _Ty;
    using _Const_thru_ref_type = const _Ty&;
};

template <class _Ty>
struct remove_reference<_Ty&&> {
    using type = _Ty;
    using _Const_thru_ref_type = const _Ty&&;
};

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by - HolyBlackCat, Adding two more reference specialisations for remove_reference fixed the problem.

```
template <class _Ty> struct remove_reference<_Ty&> 
{ using type = _Ty; using _Const_thru_ref_type = const _Ty&; }; 

template <class _Ty> struct remove_reference<_Ty&&> 
{ using type = _Ty; using _Const_thru_ref_type = const _Ty&&; };
```